# Is the row passed to getTableCellRendererComponent supposed to be in bounds?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I notice if you set a new model into a `JTable`, if the number of rows is lower than the highest selected row, this can happen:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Row index 2 is out of bounds (0..1)
    at com.acme.MyTableModel.getRowObject(MyTableModel.java:184)
    at com.acme.MyCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(MyCellRenderer.java:144)
    at javax.swing.JTable$AccessibleJTable.getAccessibleChild(JTable.java:7039)
    at javax.swing.JTable$AccessibleJTable.getAccessibleAt(JTable.java:7426)
    at javax.swing.JTable$AccessibleJTable.valueChanged(JTable.java:6939)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:184)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:164)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:211)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:405)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:415)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.removeSelectionIntervalImpl(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:576)
    at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.clearSelection(DefaultListSelectionModel.java:420)
    at javax.swing.JTable.clearSelection(JTable.java:2117)
    at javax.swing.JTable.clearSelectionAndLeadAnchor(JTable.java:2125)
    at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4370)
    at javax.swing.JTable.setModel(JTable.java:3688)
```

Whose bug is this? Should Swing be checking this index before asking for a renderer, or is it the renderer's job to check the index?

*Edit:*

Here's a much reduced example, just in case there really is a bug elsewhere. Press the button until row 5 is visible, then select row 5 and press the button again.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class BreakMyTable implements Runnable {
    JTable table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new BreakMyTable());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        table = new JTable();
        installNewModel();

        TableColumnModel columnModel = new DefaultTableColumnModel();
        TableColumn column1 = new TableColumn(0, 100);
        column1.setCellRenderer(new CustomRenderer(table.getDefaultRenderer(Integer.class)));
        columnModel.addColumn(column1);
        TableColumn column2 = new TableColumn(1, 400);
        columnModel.addColumn(column2);
        table.setColumnModel(columnModel);
        table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);

        JToolBar toolBar = new JToolBar();
        toolBar.setFloatable(false);
        toolBar.add(new AbstractAction("Replace model") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                installNewModel();
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void installNewModel() {
        int rows = table.getModel() == null ? 5 :
                   table.getModel().getRowCount() == 5 ? 6 : 5;

        DefaultTableModel model = new CustomModel(rows, 2);
        for (int row = rows - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
            model.setValueAt(row, row, 0);
        }
        table.setModel(model);
        table.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter<>(model));
    }

    private class CustomModel extends DefaultTableModel {
        public CustomModel(int rowCount, int columnCount) {
            super(rowCount, columnCount);
        }

        // In the real implementation, getValueAt() is implemented by calling getRowObject().
        public Object getRowObject(int row) {
            if (row < 0 || row >= getRowCount()) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Out of bounds: " + row);
            }

            return getValueAt(row, 0);
        }
    }

    private class CustomRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
        private final TableCellRenderer delegateRenderer;

        private CustomRenderer(TableCellRenderer delegateRenderer) {
            this.delegateRenderer = delegateRenderer;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            int modelIndex = table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
            Object rowObject = ((CustomModel) table.getModel()).getRowObject(modelIndex);
            // Would usually use the row object to decorate the cell somehow, e.g. add an icon.

            return delegateRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        }
    }
}
```

I can reproduce it quite reliably and I already know that a solution is to dodge the NPE in the renderer. I just want to know whether the values passed to the renderer are supposed to be checked before I receive them. If they are, then I will consider my solution to be a workaround and will report the bug upstream. If the renderer is supposed to check them, I will consider my solution to be a bugfix.

Comment: Short answer, yes.  This can happen if the table or model is modified outside of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Comment: If using a sorter, always remember to translate cell coordinates.

Comment: If using a (custom) sorter remember to set the new model to the sorter too. The sorter works with the model that has been initialized with, not with the model the table is using (I don't think it even has a reference to the table).

Comment: @MadProgrammer our repaint detector would have thrown an error as soon as anything like that happens.

Comment: @trashgod We are using a sorter. In the debugger, I see that convertRowIndexToModel(2) returns 2. The sorter hasn't actually been sorted on any columns and I can only guess that it still has the previous view-to-model mapping cached.

Comment: @DSquare we do that, but this error occurs directly from setModel(), which is one line before the line when we update the sorter.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error, even if I add a header value and sort.

Comment: @trashgod Since the error is coming from getAccessibleAt(), I wonder if your JVM is never calling it somehow. For instance, maybe you're running a different version (I'm on 7u45) or maybe yours has decided that there is no need to load the accessibility code.

Comment: On Mac OS X , I see `java version "1.7.0_51"`.

Comment: Just updated to 7u51 - still reproducible. Also I managed to reproduce that it *doesn't* throw the error if no accessibility features are enabled. As soon as I turn on Voice Over and restart the app, blam. So now I know a code-free workaround, but it would still be nice to know if there is a guarantee on the row value, because the main issue here is that I don't know if it's a bug or something I'm supposed to expect might happen. Incidentally, the same AccessibleJTable class is guilty of passing null values to the renderer for a model without any nulls in it.